# Should I initialize facebook and google SDK each time user opens my web application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, federated-identity, amazon-cognito

I use AWS Cognito service for authentication in my web application. Users can sign in by username and password, by google and by facebook.
I use Amazon User Pool for login by username and password. And I use Amazon Federated Identity for login by google and facebook.
When user opens my web application I get tokens from facebook and google sdk (FB.init() and gapi.client.init())

And then I create "Logins" object that used in AWS credentials:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
    Logins: {
        'graph.facebook.com': tokenFromFacebook,
        'accounts.google.com': tokenFromGoogle,
        'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>': result.getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
        ... etc
    }
});
```

Next I get credentials using `AWS.config.credentials.get()` function.

Is it right? I don't want to send requests to each social network each time user opens web application. Now I am using only google and facebook, but what if I will have more social networks?